# Android room entity data class

Tags: android, android-room, entity, typeconverter

I have such JSON structure:

```
{
 1:{street:"test1",address:"address1"},
 2:{street:"test2",address:"address2"}
}
```

Should I need create TypeConverters for it?

or this should be enough?

```
@Entity(tableName = "Address")
data class Address(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("street")
    val street: String,
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: String
)
```

Comment: your json is dictionary ... afaik there is no converter which move key to object property (1, 2 to Address.id ) ... so you have to create new TypeConverter

Comment: @Selvin can you help me to do it?

Comment: with what ... deserialize your json to dictionary/map<int, Address> then iterate keys and fill values's id with key's value